# deepfacelab ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, deeplearning4j

I'm here trying to use deepface lab and got stuck in this error while trying run second step:
Couldn't find how to solve this.

When I try to run step 2 **Extract image from video data_src**, I'm getting error in command prompt.

```
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hruthik\Downloads\DEEP FACE LAB\DeepFaceLab_NVIDIA_up_to_RTX2080Ti\_internal\python-3.6.8\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\hruthik\Downloads\DEEP FACE LAB\DeepFaceLab_NVIDIA_up_to_RTX2080Ti\_internal\python-3.6.8\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\hruthik\Downloads\DEEP FACE LAB\DeepFaceLab_NVIDIA_up_to_RTX2080Ti\_internal\python-3.6.8\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "imp.py", line 243, in load_module
  File "imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "multiprocessing\process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
  File "multiprocessing\process.py", line 93, in run
  File "C:\Users\hruthik\Downloads\DEEP FACE LAB\DeepFaceLab_NVIDIA_up_to_RTX2080Ti\_internal\DeepFaceLab\core\leras\device.py", line 102, in _get_tf_devices_proc
    import tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\hruthik\Downloads\DEEP FACE LAB\DeepFaceLab_NVIDIA_up_to_RTX2080Ti\_internal\python-3.6.8\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\hruthik\Downloads\DEEP FACE LAB\DeepFaceLab_NVIDIA_up_to_RTX2080Ti\_internal\python-3.6.8\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\hruthik\Downloads\DEEP FACE LAB\DeepFaceLab_NVIDIA_up_to_RTX2080Ti\_internal\python-3.6.8\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hruthik\Downloads\DEEP FACE LAB\DeepFaceLab_NVIDIA_up_to_RTX2080Ti\_internal\python-3.6.8\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\hruthik\Downloads\DEEP FACE LAB\DeepFaceLab_NVIDIA_up_to_RTX2080Ti\_internal\python-3.6.8\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\hruthik\Downloads\DEEP FACE LAB\DeepFaceLab_NVIDIA_up_to_RTX2080Ti\_internal\python-3.6.8\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "imp.py", line 243, in load_module
  File "imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors
```

Comment: @Haang It will be more helpful, if u can you give me solution to this problem

Comment: Can you provide the steps or code that your using to replicate the issue. Thanks!